# Bitlocker: Lock or Unlock event

Tags: windows

I am working on a data backup project.  In the case of bitlocked volume I need to wait until the bitlocker locked volume is unlocked. So is there any event by which i can get the notification as soon as the volume is unlocked?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Ticker or Loop/Sleep in a separate thread to periodically check the lock status using the GetLockStatus method of the Win32_EncryptableVolume class.

```
uint32 GetLockStatus(
  [out]  uint32 LockStatus
);
```

Returns 0 for unlocked, 1 for locked.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. I dont want to periodically poll which means I will have to wait. I am hoping for some sort of event which can be handled upon lock/unlock by registering to certain event types.